# Return the index of the common elements of two lists

Tags: python, list

So I have two lists:

The output only considers 1 and not 0

```
lst1 = [1,0,0,1,1]
lst2 = [0,0,1,1,0]
```

And the output is:

```
[3] # because the index where the elements are the same is at index 3
```

How should I code this?

The way I coded this was I tried having two loops

```
lst1 = [1,0,0,1,1]
lst2 = [0,0,1,1,0]
my_list = []

for i in range(len(lst1)):
    for i in range(len(lst2)):
        if lst1[i] == lst2[i] == 1:
            my_list.append(lst1[i])
        
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Care to show your attempt? BTW, `1` is also a valid output. Why only `3`?

Comment: oh yeah i'm so sorry, I forgot to add one of the conditions. The element has to be 1 then append

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
lst1 = [1,0,0,1,1]
lst2 = [0,0,1,1,0]
[idx for idx, (f,s) in enumerate(zip(lst1,lst2)) if f==s]
#[1,3]
```

**Edit:** base on your comment. `zip` concatenate element by element of two list. see this example:

```
a = [1,2,4,6,8]
b = [0,3,5,7,9]
list(zip(a,b))
# [(1, 0), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)]
```

Comment: It works, thank you. I never used enumerate before and I just found out what it does. Thank you

Comment: @user1740577 - You don't need the `list`. `[idx for idx, (f,s) in enumerate(zip(lst1,lst2)) if f==s]`

Comment: @not_speshal thanks for your comment. yes you are right, I edit my answer, thanks a lot

Comment: can you explain how does zip works? Never seen that before. Thank you

Comment: @BryanHii. sure. I edit the answer and add an example. maybe this helps you

Comment: @user1740577 thank you so much, I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
out=[]
for i, x, y in enumerate (zip(lst1,lst2)):
    if x==y:
        out.append(i)
```

Comment: Please avoid answering low quality questions (= no research, no effort) with low quality answers (= code-only)

Comment: @DeepSpace thanks. Sure, i will know next time to do so ;)

Answer (score 0):

The below is what you are looking for. The idea is to loop over the 2 lists and add to the results the index of the matching entries. An implicit assumption is that the 2 lists got same length.

```
result = [idx for idx,_ in enumerate(lst1) if lst1[idx] == lst2[idx]]
```

output

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I never used enumerate before and I just looked it up.